# Convert words such as "Month" to datetime

Tags: php

I'm creating a program where if I type in words like, "minutes", "hours", "days", "weeks", "months", I want them to convert into a timestamp.

Like if I were to input "8 months" and the format were to be `date('d-m-Y H:i:s');`, I want it to output 00-08-0000 00:00:00. Same goes for the rest.

I read about `strtotime` on http://php.net/ but that's when you insert time format, not words.

Is this possible at all?

I've thought about using `booleans`, but then I get a huge mess such as this:

```
<?php
    <input type="text" name="time" />

    $time = ($_POST['time']);

    if (strpos($time,'hours') !== false){ int hour = 1; }
    else if (strpos($time,'hours') !== false){ int hours = 1; }
    else if (strpos($time,'day') !== false){ int day = 1; }
    else if (strpos($time,'days') !== false){ int days = 1; }
    else if (strpos($time,'week') !== false){ int week = 1; }
    else if (strpos($time,'weeks') !== false){ int weeks = 1; }
    else if (strpos($time,'month') !== false){ int month = 1; }
    else if (strpos($time,'months') !== false){ int months = 1; }
?>
```

It has to more efficient then this.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @sgtBOSE read my edit.

Comment: @SunilPachlangia read my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use,

```
strtotime(time,now);
//time => Required. Specifies a date/time string
//now  => Optional. Specifies the timestamp used as a base for the calculation of relative dates
```

This will parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp. Some examples here:

```
strtotime("now");
strtotime("10 September 2000");
strtotime("+1 day");
strtotime("+1 week");
strtotime("+1 week 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds");
strtotime("next Thursday");
strtotime("last Monday");
```